# Access request headers class-validator nestJs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I need to validate property 'settings' with FirstDto if typeId is '1' and SecondDto if typeId is '2'.

This is my createDto class that has 'typeId' and 'settings' properties.

```
@Type(({ object }) => {
        switch(object.typeId) {
            case 1:
                return FirstDto;
            case 2:
                return SecondDto;
        }
    })
    readonly settings: FirstDto | SecondDto;
```

But problem is that i have UpdateDto class as well. And there I need only 'settings' property.
I would like to get item's id from params, inject itemsService, find item by id and get typeId value and after that validate settings by FirstDto or SecondDto